# Can not compile Assembly (.s) code with Cygwin on Win

Tags: gcc, assembly, cygwin, att

I have this ".s" file, written in AT&T assembly.

```
.globl interleave   
interleave:
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %esi
    pushl %edi
    movl 16(%esp), %ebx     #a
    movl 20(%esp), %esi     #b
    movl 24(%esp), %edi     #c
D:  movb (%ebx), %cl
    testb %cl, %cl
    jz W
    movb %cl, (%edi)            #*c
    incl %edi
    incl %ebx
T:  movb (%esi), %dl
    testb %dl, %dl
    jz W
    movb %dl, (%edi)            #*c
    incl %edi
    incl %esi
W:  orb %cl,%dl
    jz E
    #movb $0, %al
    jmp D
E:  movb $0, (%edi)
    popl %edi
    popl %esi
    popl %ebx
    ret
```

I want to compile it on windows 10 with **cygwin** with the following *main* file, but it does not work.

```
void interleave(const char* a, const char* b, char* c) ;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    const char* a = "car";
    const char* b = "old";
    char c[] = "";
    interleave(a,b,c);
    printf("%s (expected coalrd)\n", c);
    return 0;}
```

---

With `gcc` i get `es1B.s:3: Error: invalid instruction suffix for push`

With `gcc -m32` I get `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I even tried to compile it in 32 bit with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` but I get  `undefined reference to interleave`

I am able to compile it and run it on linux with `gcc -m32` , but is there a way to make this work on windows?

Thanks

Comment: You missed `.globl interleave`.

Comment: On Windows, symbol names for cdecl functions must be prefixed with an underscore. Perhaps that's why you get an “undefined reference” error?

Comment: @fuz Thank you so much, I did not know that! It works now!  :)

Comment: @Jester you're right, I corrected the code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding an *underscore* before the function name as suggested in the comments:

```
.globl _interleave
_interleave:
 ...
```

Compiling with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` now works.